# Loading Laravel to server (white screen error)

Tags: php, laravel, server

I'm trying to upload my laravel project to my shared hosting site. I changed the .env file to reflect the new database. I placed all the files from my laravel project into file-zilla as follows: [image]

I moved the contents of the laravel public folder and placed it into the database public_html folder. I have also tested to see if the index.php was being called in-which it did echo the correct response. However, when I commented in all of the actual content of the index I get nothing but a blank screen without any error. Well it flashed internal 500 error for a second before disappearing. I have read online for other laravel projects issues that they needed to simply add the laravel project files and make sure the index.php from laravel is being called upon. I even tried one solution that instructed me to do this:

Bootstrap app.php

[image]

Myapp

[image]

If anyone has any experience with laravel can you please help me get my project online?

Comment: It's possible you didn't set the [correct directory permissions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration). If you have, you should also check the error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Create folder laravel in your root directory copy all data to that folder except public folder

then copy all data from public folder to folder pubic_html

now edit your index.php in your public_html folder like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then change `Config/database.php` and insert valid data for database connection

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

[image: Third step]

[Good tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)